# SagePay Form Integration V3.0 error - 3045 : The Currency field is missing

Tags: php, opayo

Im having an issue while integrating sagepay form into a website.

I have generated the form and its posting to the correct URL but i get 3045 : The Currency field is missing when it is set.

Is there anything obviouse i may be missing here that i could check?

This leads me to believe my encrypt function is incorrect? I may be wrong but here is my function i use to encrypt the data:

```
public function encryptAndEncode($strIn, $vendorTxCode) {

    $strIV = $this->_password;

    $strIn = $this->addPKCS5Padding($strIn);

    $strCrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->_password, $strIn, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $strIV);

    return "@" . bin2hex($strCrypt);
}
```

There is no integration guides for PHP so if someone knows of a tutorial / documentation they could point me to that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: It may help to show us what `$strIn` looks like and perhaps how you build it.

Answer (score 3):

You will always get the currency error if its encrypted/encoded not in the right way. Check out the simple php class i wrote https://github.com/tolzhabayev/sagepayForm-php it does the encoding for you

Comment: doesn't appear to be anywhere to enter the vendor ID etc

Comment: @Horse i have updated the example file index.php with a sample form where you can see where you enter the vendorid and check the variable $encryptPassword inside lib/SagePay.php to set your encryption password.

Comment: great this worked! can you help i need to add multiple items to the basket but it keep coming up with an error can you show me an example? thanks

Comment: @gareth https://github.com/tolzhabayev/sagepayForm-php/blob/master/index.php#L20-L46 just add multiple items, for each item you have to createElement('item')

Answer (score 0):

When using Form, if you are getting Invalid Currency, check the casing is correct i.e. Great British Pound would be Currency=GBP and not Curreny=gbp. Also check the currency is supported on your Sage Pay account as if you are trying to process a euro transaction (Currency=EUR) when you do not have that currency assigned to your merchant number and Sage Pay, you will get an invalid currency error.

Check you are using the correct Encryption password for TEST or/and LIVE as the encryption password differs for Test and Live. The encryption password is case sensitive. It should be no more than 16 characters (base 64 encoded).

Comment: do you know how do we get Encryption password?

Comment: If ever need the Encyrption password (Test and/or Live), call Sage Pay Support on 0845 111 4455 or email support@sagepay.com and ask that it can be sent to you. It'll be sent via secure password link to you.

Comment: I have a same issue some one can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940754/status-detail-3045-the-currency-field-is-missing

Comment: Check encryption passwords are correct. Different encryption passwords for TEST/LIVE.

Comment: @Sage Pay Support,I have update my post can you please check.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940754/status-detail-3045-the-currency-field-is-missing

Comment: The encryption password can be reset and read by logging into the *MySagePay* control panel as the administrator (not a user - it has to be the main administrator).

Answer (score 0):

i had the same going on and tried almost everything including talking to sage support.

yes the encryption password is probably your problem but if you just like me are moving from server integration to form u might want to check what url you are using

my issue was the git repo that previous developer left me with had the server integration url while live site was using form leaving me with the error

check your url, had to change mine from

https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspserver-register.vsp

to

https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp

doh, hope it helps to someone