# live encryption key not working after upgrading to VPS protocol 3.00

Tags: php, opayo

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19653569/588306), I've migrated a site over to use VPS protocol 3.00.
I have done my testing against the test site with the test encryption key and all works well. When I switch this over to use the live site with the live encryption key, I get the dreaded `3045 : The Currency field is missing` error.

The same encryption key works on the live site when using VPS protocol 2.22, but not when it's switched to 3.00.

I have also fed the post data to a decryption script that is using the same key to decrypt the `crypt` without issue.

Can anyone think of why the code would work against `test.`, but not `live.` with the appropriate key, or why 2.22 accepts the key and 3.0 does not? Is `live.` doing any extra checking with 3.00 that `test.` isn't?

My code has slightly modified the functions from the integration kit:

```
function addPKCS5Padding($input) {
  $blockSize = 16;
  $padd = "";

  // Pad input to an even block size boundary.
  $length = $blockSize - (strlen($input) % $blockSize);
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++) {
    $padd .= chr($length);
  }

  return $input . $padd;
}

// AES encryption, CBC blocking with PKCS5 padding then HEX encoding.
function sagepay_encrypt($string, $key) {
  // Add PKCS5 padding to the text to be encrypted.
  $string = addPKCS5Padding($string);

  // Perform encryption with PHP's MCRYPT module.
  $crypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $key);

  // Perform hex encoding and return.
  return "@" . strtoupper(bin2hex($crypt));
}
```

It is called by populating the `$crypt_values` array and calling:

```
$crypt_source = sagepay_buildcrypt($crypt_values);
$crypt = sagepay_encrypt($crypt_source, $sagepay_key);
```

The `$crypt_source` is valid and (largely) the same in all cases:

```
VendorTxCode=20150721020857Deannatest&VendorData=Deanna test&Amount=1&Currency=GBP&Description=Quote Reference Deanna test&BillingSurname=Earley&BillingFirstnames=Deanna&BillingAddress1.....
```

Comment: I can give access to the test site and demonstrate all combinations if required.

Comment: If you can supply the vendor name, I can look into it for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the encryption password, its too short by one character. I've updated it by adding 'X' (upper case) to the end, so just update your value accordingly.

I've given it a try and it is now fine.

I'm assuming you are using the password that begins '3Gd' (if not let me know).

Comment: For anyone else with this issue - your encryption key should be 16 characters. If it isn't, you'll need to contact Sage Pay

Comment: Thank you, appending X to the key worked. I assume this will break the XOR method too?

Comment: Yes. You will need to make sure that both XOR and AES use the same password from now on (though Sage Pay will be turning off the XOR side of things in 10 days)

Comment: Thanks, our live site has been updated with the new key, and all is working on both sites.